# Font bold does not work in Xcode 8

Tags: fonts, swift3, xcode8, ios10, bold

Now, I'm using Xcode 8. I would like to bold the text and I choose semibold from the Attributes Inspector. 
When I run the app in iPad (iOS 10), it does not bold. 

 Is this a bug of Xcode8 ? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 - Xcode 8.1

```
label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 40)
```